# C++ - Constructor Inheritance with private parameters

Tags: c++, inheritance, parameters

Hello I have trouble with working an inheritance constructor. I can't access the parent's fields.

Here is my MyClass.h:

```
#include "Parent.h"
class MyClass : public Parent {
  public:
    MyClass(string otherParameters);

};
```

Here is MyClass.cpp:

```
#include MyClass.h
MyClass::MyClass(string otherParameters) : Parent() {
    parent_field = "something";
}
```

The field otherParameters does not come from Parent and pertains only to the class MyCLass. 
The compiler pops out errors and tells me Parent::parent_field is private. I don't undersrtand, my class MyClass should have inherited this parent_field attribute, so why can't I have access to it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's `private`. Functions and variables in the `private` section of a class is only available to that class and that class alone. If you want to be able to use functions or variables in inherited classes, but still not allow them to be `public`, you have to put them in the `protected` section.

Answer (score 1):

`MyClass` only has access to `Parent`'s `public` and `protected` members. If `parent_field` is a private member of `Parent`, then `MyClass` cannot see it (unless you declare `MyClass` to be a friend of `Parent`, which would be an odd design).

It looks like you want to be able to set `parent_field` via a `Parent` constructor:

```
struct Parent
{
  Parent(const std::string& s) : parent_field(s) {}
  // other code as before
};
```

then use it in `MyClass`'s constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass(string otherParameters) : Parent("something") {}
```

This would set `Parent::parent_field` to `"something"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [good question discussing access modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020749/what-are-public-private-and-protected-in-object-oriented-programming),
`private`, `protected` and `public`. `private` is only visible by your class, not to anyone inheriting from it. What you need to do is either declare `parent_field` protected in `Parent`, or have some other way of accessing it, like having a setter or constructor argument.

Also, the fact that you inherit it as `public` means, that anyone inheriting from `MyClass` will not have a restricted view of `Parent`, however, `Parent` still decides what it wants to expose, how you inherit it doesn't change that. The only thing you can do is *restrict* how classes inheriting `MyClass` is able to access stuff from `Parent`, but you cannot remove any restrictions imposed already.